# Active Admin rollback: "Validation failed: Email has already been taken"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rollback, activeadmin, rails-migrations

I'm at the start of a project in Rails 3.1.3 with a postgresql backend.

I generated a few models and then added the *Active Admin* gem.
A bit later I decided that I should combine 2 models, and wanted to rollback to the beginning so I could delete one model and restart the migration with the correct schema.

I typed:

```
rake db:rollback step=10
```

It went well up to the *Active Admin* bit, when it aborted the rollback:

```
$ rake db:rollback
==  DeviseCreateAdminUsers: reverting =========================================
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Validation failed: Email has already been taken

Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
```

I have not added any users, so this is probably the 'admin@example.com' account.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

gem 'pg'
gem 'json'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
gem 'meta_search',    '>= 1.1.0.pre'
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'mechanize'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: did you fix this? got the same problem ...

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you do the 10 step rollback, in 2 stages? The question you pose is a bit underspecified, hard to give you a good answer. Apart from pointing you to this piece of information

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Migrations#Managing_Migrations

I suggest you check all your migrations for a

```
AdminUser.create
```

statement. You may also want to manually remove the AdminUser using the rails console.

Answer (score 0):

run `rake db:reset` before the rollback.

Answer (score 0):

The devise_create_admin_users migration creates a default user on migrate:up but then tries to create it again on rollback/migrate:down. Hence the validation error, as the email already exists.

Just comment out the 'AdminUser.create!' before rolling back, and then uncomment it when rolling back up.